# Cloudflare Access: Grab Authenticated user email

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I created a Cloudflare Access self-hosted application, with a policy to allow users with emails from a specific domain to login via One Time Pin.

The login works correctly and I am trying to get the email of logged in users so that I can use it in my application (for example to filter data that only pertains to that user).

I [read](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/how-to-know-which-user-has-passed-the-cloudflare-access/268630) that I am supposed to see the email the user used to login/pass the policy in the headers:

```
"Cf-Access-Authenticated-User-Email":
"Cf-Access-Jwt-Assertion":
```

Unfortunately I don’t see any of these headers after logging in via OTP. Does anyone know why and how I can access this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a CF_Authorization header in the form of a JWT. Decoding the JWT, the email is available as a field.